# Vaadin 7 : How to update Cookie value?

Tags: cookies, vaadin, vaadin7

Methods for cookie management these I use as below

```
public static Cookie getCookieByName(final String name) {
    // Fetch all cookies from the request
    Cookie[] cookies = VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getCookies();

    // Iterate to find cookie by its name
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        if (name.equals(cookie.getName())) {
            return cookie;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public static Cookie createCookie(final String name, final String value, final int maxAge) {
    // Create a new cookie
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);

    cookie.setMaxAge(maxAge);

    // Set the cookie path.
    cookie.setPath(VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getContextPath());

    // Save cookie
    VaadinService.getCurrentResponse().addCookie(cookie);

    return cookie;
}

public static Cookie updateCookieValue(final String name, final String value) {
    // Create a new cookie
    Cookie cookie = getCookieByName(name);

    cookie.setValue(value);

    // Save cookie
    VaadinService.getCurrentResponse().addCookie(cookie);

    return cookie;
}

public static void destroyCookieByName(final String name) {
    Cookie cookie = getCookieByName(name);

    if (cookie != null) {
        cookie.setValue(null);
        // By setting the cookie maxAge to 0 it will deleted immediately
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        VaadinService.getCurrentResponse().addCookie(cookie);
    }
}
```

I can select,create and destroy for cookies but I can't update cookie's value with my method `updateCookieValue(final String name, final String value)` . I tested in both Firefox and Chrome browser as `updateCookieValue(LOCALE_COOKIE, "en");` but locale value of browsers didn't change. What's wrong with my method ?

Comment: The code it's right. Try to remove "static" from all the methods.

Comment: @PaoloForgia Right ? I don't think so because my **locale** cookie does not change by my `updateCookieValue()` method. Btw , why you suggest to remove *static* ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Vaadin with Push you can only update cookies while executing UI.init() method. There is currently no workaround for this problem.

http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/11808

Comment: I am not using with server-push , created in a simple UI class and try to change by selected combobox value. You can see in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278825/internationalization-in-vaadin-with-property-file) question how I am using. Now I call `destroyCookie()` method first and re-create new cookie by `createCookie()` method. I have no idea why I can't use with `updateCookie()` method.