# Internationalization in Vaadin with property file

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I found a [useful example](http://dev.vaadin.com/browser/svn/incubator/gasdiary?order=name) for internationalization in Vaadin. Here is [online-demo](http://magi.virtuallypreinstalled.com/gasdiary/?restartApplication) for this. I tried with combobox for locale change as ..

```
private Locale localeMyanmar, localeEnglish;
private static final String LOCALE_COOKIE = "locale";
.......
localeMyanmar = new Locale("my", "Burmese");
localeEnglish = Locale.ENGLISH;
.........
    final ComboBox cbLanguage = new ComboBox();
    cbLanguage.addStyleName("comboIconCaption");
    cbLanguage.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    cbLanguage.setImmediate(true);

    IndexedContainer ic = new IndexedContainer();
    ic.addItem("Myanmar");
    ic.addItem("English");
    cbLanguage.setContainerDataSource(ic);

    cbLanguage.setItemIcon("Myanmar", new ThemeResource("img/Myanmar-flag.png"));
    cbLanguage.setItemIcon("English", new ThemeResource("img/US-flag.png"));

    Cookie localeCookie = getCookieByName(LOCALE_COOKIE);
    if (localeCookie != null && localeCookie.getValue() != null) {
        if (localeCookie.getValue().equals("my")) {
            cbLanguage.setValue("Myanmar");
            setLocale(localeMyanmar);
        }
        else {
            cbLanguage.setValue("English");
            setLocale(localeEnglish);
        }
    }
    else {
        cbLanguage.setValue("Myanmar");
        // Create a new cookie , 2678400 = 1 month
        localeCookie = createCookie(LOCALE_COOKIE, "my", 2678400);
        setLocale(localeMyanmar);
    }
    message.initializeMessageResource(getLocale());

    cbLanguage.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

        public void valueChange(final ValueChangeEvent event) {
            if (cbLanguage.getValue().toString().equals("Myanmar")) {
                destroyCookieByName(LOCALE_COOKIE);
                createCookie(LOCALE_COOKIE, "my", 2678400);
                setLocale(localeMyanmar);
            }
            else {
                destroyCookieByName(LOCALE_COOKIE);
                createCookie(LOCALE_COOKIE, "en", 2678400);
                setLocale(localeEnglish);
            }
            message.initializeMessageResource(getLocale());

        }
    });
```

Message.java

```
public class Message implements Serializable {
private ResourceBundle i18n;

public final void initializeMessageResource(final Locale locale) {
    i18n = ResourceBundle.getBundle(OfficeMessage.class.getName(), locale);
}
public final String getLocalizeMessage(final String key) {
    return i18n.getString(key);
}
}
```

OfficeMessage.java

```
public class OfficeMessage extends ListResourceBundle implements Serializable {
@Override
protected Object[][] getContents() {
    return null;
}
public static String generateId() {
    return new Integer(ids++).toString();
}

private static int ids = 0;

// Constants
public static final String OK = generateId();
public static final String CANCEL = generateId();
public static final String SAVE = generateId();
public static final String RESET = generateId();
}
```

OfficeMessage_my.java

```
public class OfficeMessage_my extends OfficeMessage {
@Override
public final Object[][] getContents() {
    return contents_en;
}

static final Object[][] contents_en = {
        // Basic Buttons Text
        { OK, "သဘောတူသည်" },
        { CANCEL, "သဘောမတူပါ" },
        { SAVE, "သိမ်းမည်" },
        { RESET, "နဂိုအတိုင်းပြန်ထားမည်" },
};
}
```

OfficeMessage_en.java

```
public class OfficeMessage_en extends OfficeMessage {
@Override
public final Object[][] getContents() {
    return contents_en;
}

static final Object[][] contents_en = {
        // Basic Buttons Text
        { OK, "OK" },
        { CANCEL, "Cancel" },
        { SAVE, "Save" },
        { RESET, "Reset" },
};
}
```

And call for internationalize as `btnUpdate.setCaption(message.getLocalizeMessage(OfficeMessage.OK));`.

My questions are

1. I don't want to create with constant java classes . I would like to
   create with **properties** files *(eg: OfficeMessage_my.properties ,
   OfficeMessage_en.properties)*. I didn't find any references for
   this. Please somebody help me how can I do with **xxx.properties**
   files.
2. How to do for messages ? I also want to create messages *(may be dynamic)* with internationalize. For example :`message.sayHello(currentLoginUser)`. When I want to use dynamic messages , How can I figure it out ?

Comment: For using cookie , pls check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278345/vaadin-7-how-to-update-cookie-value) question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to create both *Constants* and *Messages* with properties files via [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/customized-internationalization-i18n-in.html) link.
Finally , My *Constants* and *Messages* classes as below ,

**Constants.java**

```
public class Constants implements Serializable {
private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "myProject.i18n.Constants.Constants";
private ResourceBundle i18n;

public final void init(final Locale locale) {
    i18n = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, locale);
}
public final String getConstantValue(final String key) {
    try {
        return new String(i18n.getString(key).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return '!' + key + '!';
    }
    catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        return '!' + key + '!';
    }
}
}
```

**Messages.java**

```
public class Messages implements Serializable {
private static final String BASE_NAME = "myProject.i18n.Messages.Messages";
private ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
private Locale locale;

public final void init(final Locale locale) {
    this.locale = locale;
    messageSource.setBasename(BASE_NAME);
}

public final String getMessageValue(final String key) {
    try {
        return new String(messageSource.getMessage(key, null, locale).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return '!' + key + '!';
    }
    catch (NoSuchMessageException e) {
        return '!' + key + '!';
    }
}

public final String getMessageValue(final String key, final Object[] parameters) {
    try {
        return new String(messageSource.getMessage(key, parameters, locale).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return '!' + key + '!';
    }
    catch (NoSuchMessageException e) {
        return '!' + key + '!';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I see that you also solved your problem. May I ask if this was your final approach and it worked as you wanted? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checkout a sample solution in regards to Internationalization (i18n) in vaadin and Spring framework, implemented by Jaroslav H. in 'Vaadin 7 Cookbook'

- https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin-spring-webinar/tree/master/i18n
- https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3704190